# Azure invite using Graph API, no token in redirect url

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I successfully followed this guide:

https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/invite-aad-user-microsoft-graph/

and can use the Graph API to invite and add users to my Azure tenant.

I'm having a problem with the callback that the user is redirected to after authenticating, I want the user to be authenticated and so I was expecting an auth token to be returned as part of the callback, but there's nothing there.

I can find much information about this issue so I wonder if I'm doing it wrong.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The invite api doesn't work for B2C scenarios. It is more suited for B2B scenarios.

Invitation api documentation - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

If this is a B2C scenario, could you please explain a bit more about what are you planning to achieve?